# performance tests/metrics and tools

Tags: automated-tests, hyperledger-fabric, performance-testing, blockchain

I have to test the performance of a blockchain(hyperledgerFabric) RESTAPI application.
Can any one help me what performance metrics should I choose
Is there a tool that simulate blockchain network or I can use Jmeter/Gatling or it is better to use a spectial tools for blockchain if yes witch one?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend starting by reading a couple of Blogs on Fabric Performance. There has been work done on performance and scaling and there's [white papers](https://www.hyperledger.org/resources/publications/blockchain-performance-metrics) and [blogs](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/blockchain/2019/01/answering-your-questions-on-hyperledger-fabric-performance-and-scale/) on the internet for it.

There's a bunch of [metrics already available in Fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/metrics_reference.html) you can leverage for your work as well.  Enjoy!